# Afnetworking offline mode without cache (save into file Like Imageloader in android)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i want to use afnetworking method to download and show image into imageview.

another step is i want to save all image in case of user open application in offline mode.

there is a few article on SO that give method on how to use UrlCache and cache variable in url header.

with background of developing in android is there any way to make Afnetworking works like Imageloader

solution in android ? (saving file into program or document folder and retrive in offline mode)

this is my code for showing images in uicolleciotn view :

```
    if (![appRecord.thumb_url isEqualToString:@""])
    {

        [myCell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.thumb_url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]];
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = myCell.imageView;
        NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.thumb_url]];
        [myCell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request1
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]
                             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                 UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                                 if (!strongImageView) return;

                                 [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                                   duration:0.3
                                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                                 animations:^{
                                                     strongImageView.image = image;
                                                 }
                                                 completion:NULL];
                             }
                             failure:NULL];

    }
```

after changing the code due to **luvacu** suggestion :

adding this to header :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLRequest *strongRequest1;
```

and  :

```
        __block UIImageView *weakImageView = myCell.imageView;
        NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.thumb_url]];
        __block NSURLRequest *weakRequest1 = request1;
        [myCell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request1
                                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                             UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                                             if (!strongImageView) {
                                                 return;
                                             }

                                             [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                                               duration:0.3
                                                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                                             animations:^{
                                                                 strongImageView.image = image;
                                                             }
                                                             completion:NULL];
                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                             NSURLRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest1;
                                              UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView;
                                             UIImage *cachedImage = [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:strongRequest];
                                             if (cachedImage) {
                                                 [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                                                   duration:0.3
                                                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                                                 animations:^{
                                                                     strongImageView.image = cachedImage;
                                                                 }
                                                                 completion:NULL];
                                             }
                                         }];
```

still no iamge apear after making program offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking's category `UIImageView+AFNetworking` includes a NSCache for each image URL request. Try to load a cached image for that request, when the request fails.

```
    __block UIImageView *weakImageView = myCell.imageView;
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.thumb_url]];
    __block NSURLRequest *weakRequest1 = request1;
    [myCell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request1
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                             UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                             if (!strongImageView) {
                                 return;
                             }

                             [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                               duration:0.3
                                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                             animations:^{
                                                 strongImageView.image = image;
                                             }
                                             completion:NULL];
                         }
                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                             NSURLRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest1;
                             UIImage *cachedImage = [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:strongRequest]
                             if (cachedImage) {
                                 [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                                               duration:0.3
                                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                                             animations:^{
                                                 strongImageView.image = cachedImage;
                                             }
                                             completion:NULL];
                             }
                         }];
```

Also, you are loading the image twice. Remove the first one:

```
[myCell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appRecord.thumb_url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , i used your code but it give me error for unknown variable "strongRequest1".
if thats the same varibale as  NSURLRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest1; , its unreachable in this section of code. should i make the strongRequest variable in header and use it in both place ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I've edited the answer. You should move `NSURLRequest *strongRequest = weakRequest1;` to the 'failure' block and use `strongRequest` to retrieve the image from the cache.

Comment: Ive changed as u mentioned , the only thing that I've added was the "UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView;" inside failure block. but still don't have any image. I've updated my question with suggestion.